# Drop-down with all available files from a location in Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

Is it possible to have a UI drop-down in a Build Pipeline (like the one from predefined parameters) but containing all files available in a specific location?

I know a similar feature exist in a Release Pipeline for artifacts where you can select a specific artifact and use it,  but I need to be able to select a specific file in a Build Pipeline.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your needs are not clear from your question. What goal do you want to achieve?

In [classic pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops), you can select locations from the linked repository:

[image]

There is the artifact browser in classic and yaml pipelines:

[image]

[image]